# Ordering Table Columns - Powershell

Tags: powershell

Good Afternoon,

I have the following script to generate a table as part of a html report that I have:

```
(import-csv "C:\AutoTasks\server.txt" | 
% {new-object psobject -property @{
"Asset Number"=$_.Computer;
"Region"=$_.Description; 
"Online Status"=(test-connection -computername $_.Computer -quiet -count 1);
"Online Since"= Try {(([Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime((gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_.Computer -ErrorAction Stop).LastBootUpTime)))} Catch {"Offline"} ;
"Service"=((Get-Service -ComputerName $_.Computer | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq "ServiceName"}).Status);
"Disk Size (GB)" = ([Math]::Round(((get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername $_.Computer -Filter $_.Drive).size)/1Gb,2));
"Free Disk Space (GB)" = ([Math]::Round(((get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername $_.Computer -Filter $_.Drive).freespace)/1Gb,2));
"Free Disk Space %" = ([Math]::Round(100*(([Math]::Round(((get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername $_.Computer -Filter $_.Drive).freespace)/1Gb,2)) / ([Math]::Round(((get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername $_.Computer -Filter $_.Drive).size)/1Gb,2))),2))
 }} | ConvertTo-HTML -as Table -Fragment -PreContent "<h2>Backup Machines</h2>" | Out-String)
```

It does everything I need.

However, my issue is with the column ordering. It doesn't display in the column order I've listed, and there is seemingly no logic behind the order it offers.

Any ideas how I can specify the order, am I missing a format-table statement somewhere? My searches are drawing a blank.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using? (`$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`)

Comment: It's version 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell 3.0 and newer, you can use the `[ordered]` attribute on a hashtable literal to indicate that you want an ordered dictionary instead:

```
(import-csv "C:\AutoTasks\server.txt" | 
% {new-object psobject -property $([ordered]@{
"Asset Number"=$_.Computer;
"Region"=$_.Description; 
"Online Status"=(test-connection -computername $_.Computer -quiet -count 1);
"Online Since"= Try {(([Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime((gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_.Computer -ErrorAction Stop).LastBootUpTime)))} Catch {"Offline"} ;
"Service"=((Get-Service -ComputerName $_.Computer | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq "ServiceName"}).Status);
"Disk Size (GB)" = ([Math]::Round(((get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername $_.Computer -Filter $_.Drive).size)/1Gb,2));
"Free Disk Space (GB)" = ([Math]::Round(((get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername $_.Computer -Filter $_.Drive).freespace)/1Gb,2));
"Free Disk Space %" = ([Math]::Round(100*(([Math]::Round(((get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername $_.Computer -Filter $_.Drive).freespace)/1Gb,2)) / ([Math]::Round(((get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername $_.Computer -Filter $_.Drive).size)/1Gb,2))),2))
 })} | ConvertTo-HTML -as Table -Fragment -PreContent "<h2>Backup Machines</h2>" | Out-String)
```

Comment: That works perfect, thank you for the information.